# Past tense used to mean an universal truth?

Tags: grammaticality

> The more and more technology developed, the more and more relationships turned fake.

I feel this is a grammatically correct sentence. But what is the underlying concept here? Past tense is used (viz, developed, turned) in the sentence, yet it says an universal truth for which we generally use simple present tense. Can you please help me in figuring out the underlying concept here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's ***not*** talking about a universal truth. It's talking about what actually happened in the past. Maybe it actually is a universal truth, but that's not implied by the grammar.

Comment: But isn't what the sentence says happening now too? Actually, one of my friends posted this on fb. So, he means it happened only in past and not happening today? Forgive my ignorance pls.

Comment: It might also be happening now (that's not ruled out by the sentence), but it's not inevitable that it is going to continue happening in the future.

Comment: user108579: Your sample sentence isn't grammatical, and it doesn't look like the kind of mistakes native speakers might make anyway. But putting that aside, we use ***present*** tense to refer to "enduring" truths. [*The more people have, the more they want,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+more+people+have%2C+the+more+they+want%22) for example.

Comment: That an historical truth, not an 'universal' one.

Comment: Don't you mean relationship**s**?

Comment: As already mentioned, it's not a universal truth. Grammatically it's a correlative comparison construction which indicates a parallel (or proportional) increase along the two scales expressed by "more and more" in each clause. It can be glossed for comparative purposes as "As technology developed more and more, so relationships turned more and more fake".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more standard way to write that sentence:

> The more technology has developed, the more relationships have turned fake.

It does not purport to present a *universal* truth; it allows for the possibility that, sometime in the future, we will hit Peak Fake.